# Mongo node js query implicit $and

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

It should only update and return results that have match on the request data.

it should be not mutually exclusive (i.e. if one query does not match then do not return result results)

is using implicit $and a solution to that ?

## Query

```
  keystone.list('Vehicle').model.update({ $or: [{ Body: { $in: req.body.data[0].body } }, { Model: { $in: req.body.data[0].model } }, { Make: { $in: req.body.data[0].make } }, { Year: { $in: req.body.data[0].year } }] }, {
                    $set: {
                        'Summer_Sale_Event': req.body.summer_sale_value
                    }
                }, {
                    'multi': true
                }).exec(function (err, result) {

                });
```

## Request data

```
Request : [ { body: [ 'Convertible' ],
    make: [ 'Chevrolet' ],
    year: [ '2005' ],
    model: [ 'Corvette' ] } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$or` means that only one of the condition have to be true.
You should be using `$and` instead.